# In R, what's the most efficient way to check if an object meets a criteria, and if it doesn't, modify it?

Tags: r, if-statement, join, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have many cuts of my data that I eventually join together into one large dataset. However, sometimes the object is an error message because it didn't have enough sample size, causing the code to fail.

Before I do my full_joins, I want a simple way to say "If the length of any of these objects is 1, then make that object--and only those objects--have this set structure with just NAs". Is there a simple way to do that other than an if statement for each object? Or, alternatively, is there a way for R to 'skip' over the problematic rows if there's an error message (without relying on any specific characters)? I've used try(), but that doesn't always work and sometimes stops continuing to other joins.

```
#Here's an example of my data
library(dplyr)
object_1 <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey"), month = c("Jan", "Jan"), score = c(1, 2))

object_2 <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey"), month = c("Feb", "Feb"), score = c(100, 200))

object_3 <- "error message!"

object_4 <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey"), month = c("Apr", "Apr"), score = c(95, 23))

object_5 <- "Another error!!"

#Here's me trying to join them, but it isn't working because of the errors
all_the_objects <- object_1 %>%
  full_join(object_2) %>%
  full_join(object_3) %>%
  full_join(object_4) %>%
  full_join(object_5) 

#Here's a solution that works, but doesn't seem very elegant:

if(length(object_1) == 1) {
  object_1 <- tibble(name = NA, month = NA, score = NA_real_)
} else if(length(object_2) == 1) {
  object_2 <- tibble(name = NA, month = NA, score = NA_real_)
} else if(length(object_3) == 1) {
  object_3 <- tibble(name = NA, month = NA, score = NA_real_)
} else if(length(object_4) == 1) {
  object_4 <- tibble(name = NA, month = NA, score = NA_real_)
} else if(length(object_5) == 1) {
  object_5 <- tibble(name = NA, month = NA, score = NA_real_)
}

#Now it'll work
all_the_objects <- object_1 %>%
  full_join(object_2) %>%
  full_join(object_3) %>%
  full_join(object_4) %>%
  full_join(object_5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may place the objects in a list and do the check at once and then join with `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(mget(ls(pattern = '^object_\\d+$')), 
   ~ if(is.vector(.x)) tibble(name = NA_character_, month = NA_character_,
        score = NA_real_) else .x) %>% 
  reduce(full_join)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  name   month score
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 Justin Jan       1
2 Corey  Jan       2
3 Justin Feb     100
4 Corey  Feb     200
5 <NA>   <NA>     NA
6 Justin Apr      95
7 Corey  Apr      23
```

Comment: Great solution! One comment in case anyone in the future needs this solution, but your objects all have different names, you can make the pattern into an or statement. For instance, if you had object_1, object_2, and random_name, you could do pattern = '^object_\\d+$|random_name' Just remember not to add a space before or after the " | ". Thanks @akrun!